# Ruby return different type in "array.each"

Tags: ruby, arrays, idioms

Please consider this code:

```
    board = entities.each { |e| return if not findBoard( e ).nil? }
```

It should do exactly the same as:

```
    for e in entities
        board = findBoard( e )

        if not board.nil?
            break
        end
    end
```

but the first one does not work while the second one goes fine.

`entities`is an array of `Entity` objects and `findBoard()` returns a `Board` object or `nil`.

`Entity` and `Board` are not related classes.

I know that the second code works fine but since I am starting to learn Ruby, I am wondering if it is any more elegant way to do this so I ask, is it possible for an `each` method to return a different object type other than the objects in array (I guess it should)?

Really thanks.

Comment: Isn't this equivalent to `board = entities.detect { |e| findBoard(e) }`?

Comment: @Stefan - detect will return entity for which board exists, not a board.

Comment: @BroiSatse ah, you're right!

Comment: Testing with `nil?` is only really relevant if you're expecting `board` to be literal `false`, something that's probably not the case here. A more concise `if board` would suffice here.

Comment: Stylewise, `if not.board.nil?; break; end` is better written `break unless board.nil?`, or with @tadman's suggestion, `break if board`.

Comment: You can fix the first one easily: `def find_it(entities); entities.each { |e| fb = find_board(e); return fb if fb }; nil; end`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is unfortunately no perfectly clean way of doing this in Ruby. I'd suggest the mildly ugly

```
board = nil
entities.find { |e| board = findBoard( e ) }
board
```

`find` will work the same as `each` except that it will short-circuit as soon as board is set to a non-nil value.

Comment: Why ugly?  I find it both efficient and easy to read.  You might add `board` as a third line to emphasize that `find` is not returning the answer.

Comment: Very good. Works very well and is clear and readable. I would never think about putting the `board = ` inside... Really thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a [lazy enumerator](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-lazy):

```
board = entities.lazy.map { |e| find_board(e) }.detect { |b| b }
```

Comment: This looks like the cleanest solution just would replace `entries` with `entities` like in OP and variable name in detect block with `b` (for example) as elements are boards now and it can confuse with previous variable used for collection.

Comment: Stefan, I've given you +1 for cleverness, but I've got to ask: would you really use this, rather than one of the other answers, or something simple, like, `e = entities.find {..}; e ? : find_board(e) : nil?`  Don't forget: you are under oath.

Comment: @CarySwoveland probably not, I would use a simple loop and wrap it in a method :)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
board = entities.find {|e| b = findBoard(e) and break b }
```

Comment: Assigning board twice, once in loop, once outside??

Comment: @mdesantis - Then if no board is found it will return `entities`. With `find` it returns `nil`.

Comment: Yes I realized it after; anyway, +1 for this

Answer (score -1):

```
board = nil
entities.each { |e| board = findBoard(e) ; break unless board.nil?}
```

Comment: It does not work. `board` will still be an `Entity` array after assignment, and not a `Board` returned by `findBoard()`.